# Error #EANF# For Extracting Link using Imacros

Tags: imacros

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:Details__title___2IOjv<SP>Video__title___2-YXN EXTRACT =TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:Details__title___2IOjv<SP>Video__title___2-YXN EXTRACT =HREF
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\ajonksb\Documents\iMacros\Datasources FILE=TESTING.csv
```

l get error, the output :
Col 1 => Ice bucket challenge my dog  FUNNY ! Col 2 => #EANF#

can someone tell me how to get link videos... how to solve this error, thanks

Comment: That means there is no `href`attribute, can you provide the website?

Answer (score 0):

you can post the url EXTRACT needed